# Some actions no longer work in Konqueror

Tags: bug, status-declined, browsers

I have been using Konqueror to participate in SE sites since always. But since two days ago it no longer works. I can open any page, but some actions no longer work, incl.:

- opening a list of comments "add / show 2 more comments"
- upvoting a comment
- being able to see tag suggestions when asking a question

Konqueror version being used: "4.4.5 (KDE 4.4.5)" (I didn't do any upgrades recently).

Comment: First guess, as always: stale cache? we've made some changes to the JavaScript lately; if your browser has incorrectly cached old data, that might indeed cause problems. Does a hard refresh solve the issues?

Comment: never mind; just fired up Konqueror and seeing some issues... Checking.

Comment: Ick, yeah, that's fugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the site with Konqueror, there seem indeed to be some issues with jQuery (happen on the jQuery homepage as well).

Since [neither we](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported/56192#56192) [nor jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Browser_Compatibility) officially support Konqueror, I'm afraid all you can do is file a bug with Konqueror (or with jQuery; but that would probably have to be accompanied by a patch, I guess).

Let me add a personal note: After fighting with Konqueror's debugger for half an hour, I'm kinda glad I don't have to do that too often.

Comment: Allow me to agree... even though Konqueror is distantly related to Chrome - they're not comparable.

Comment: That's rapidly going to take it to the "sorry, can't help you" level.. While things (everything considered) do move fast at camp KDE, It's a _lot_ of things.

Comment: That's too bad. But anyway, thanks for your effort. I use Konqueror daily at home, but looks like I need to find another Personal Favorite Browser. Currently I am giving Chromium a chance.